# How to put a variable in my JS regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

this is my regex:

```
/^(\d|\d{2,}):node_type$/gm
```

But I need to parameterizing it with

```
var myVar = "a value";
var regex = /^(\d|\d{2,}):+myVar+$/gm;
```

I know this is not possibile in this way and I know that I need to using:

```
var regex = new RegExp(...);
```

So my question is how can I use RegExp to parameterizing my regex with myVar?

Comment: `var regex = new RegExp("^\\d+:"+myVar+"$", "gm");`. But you might want to escape the `myvar`, too.

Comment: Why have you changed my regex from /^(\d|\d{2,}):node_type$/gm to /^\d:node_type$/gm ?

Comment: Because that is what it looks like after you realize `(\d|\d{2,})` = `\d+`.